# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, error-handling

I have the following code

```py
rf = RandomForestClassifier()
rf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
print("Features sorted by their score:")
print(sorted(zip(map(lambda x: round(x, 2), rf.feature_importances_), X_train), reverse=True))
```

and I get the following error:

```
> TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
>
> ipython-input-109-c48c3ffd74e2> in <module>()
> 
> 2 rf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
> 
> 3 print ("Features sorted by their score:")
> 
> ----> 4 print (sorted(zip(map(lambda x: round(x, 2),
> rf.feature_importances_), X_train), reverse=True))
> 
> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I only have int and float in my dataframe.

Comment: What library are you attempting to use?

Comment: I am just using Numpy, Pandas and sklearn

Comment: I guess `rf.feature_importances_` are strings.

Comment: I checked. Its decimal values

Comment: What about X_train?

Comment: X_train has values like 1.0, 2.0 etc

Comment: Yes. got the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83494/discussion-between-psnh-and-media).

Comment: From only the code above, it should not raise the error

Comment: You must have `NA` in your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on our discussion, omit `reverse = True` and use list instead of sorted and print it. I guess you will see what you want.

Comment: Have you found the answer why the error raised?

Comment: Yes, actually. Have you seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12791957/5120235)?

Comment: I still don't understand. I tried above code, and no error.

Comment: Do you have the same data?

Comment: No. ok then it might be something wrong in `X_train`